# Synthesis of sodium ferricyanide

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, synthesis

I need to synthesize sodium ferricyanide, $\ce{Na3Fe(CN)6}$, for some benchtop experiments where I don't want any potassium ions in solution. The way I am doing that right now is oxidizing $\ce{Na4Fe(CN)6}$ using sodium permanganate, $\ce{NaMnO4}$, and filtering out the $\ce{MnO2}$ that forms. However, upon reviewing the [SDS](https://www.fishersci.com/store/msds?partNumber=AC459290010&productDescription=SODIUM%20FERROCYANIDE%20DECA%201KG&vendorId=VN00032119&countryCode=US&language=en) for sodium ferrocyanide, I found that strong oxidizing agents are an incompatible material (I am not sure why). Is there a better way to go about doing this synthesis?

Comment: How do you define a "better" way? What aspect of your present method is making you unsatisfied?

Comment: Usually this operation is made by bubbling gaseous chlorine $\ce{Cl2}$ into a sodium ferrocyanide solution.  You will obtain sodium ferricyanide plus sodium chloride, which usually does not disturb further reactions.

Comment: @orthocresol I edited the original post. The SDS mentions strong oxidizing agents are incompatible with sodium ferrocyanide.

Comment: @OscarLanzi you can buy $\ce{NaMnO4}$ commercially.

Answer (score 1):

As @Maurice said, it can be made by bubbling gaseous chlorine into a sodium ferrocyanide solution. You will obtain sodium ferricyanide plus sodium chloride, which will not disturb further reactions.

$$\ce{2Na4[Fe(CN)6] + Cl2 -> 2Na3[Fe(CN)6] + 2NaCl}$$

There is also [a patent](https://patentimages.storage.googleapis.com/pdfs/US2353782.pdf) which mentioned electrolytic oxidation of sodium ferrocyanide:

$$\ce{2Na4[Fe(CN)6] + 2H2O -> 2Na3[Fe(CN)6] + 2NaOH + H2}$$

You can find  a detailed description of the setup in the patent.

Comment: Your method can work but you have to find a way to separate the insoluble MnO2.

Comment: This seems like a good way to do it and I see that it's listed as a common reaction done with potassium ferrocyanide to form potassium ferricyanide. However $\ce{Cl_2}$ is a strong oxidizing agent, and those are supposed to be incompatible with $\ce{Na_3[Fe(CN)_6}]$ according to the SDS.

Comment: Is there a way to do this and know the exact concentration of NaCl formed? Because I suppose I won't know how much of $\ce{Cl_2}$ I passed reacted with the system?